# How to search for data in a range when some cells contain multiple values

Tags: excel

I have a large data range that i am trying to match up with another data range. Unfortunately i have multiple instances in which i have multiple data values in one cell. For instance a3 might be "10ab1" but a4 might be "10a, 10ab1, 9a". The data is always separated with a comma if there is more than one value. Sometimes there will be a number in with it e.g. "2504, 10ab1". 
I have a list of values i am searching for. (10ab would be one of them) If i find the value i want to conditionally color the cell. in this case A4 would be colored b/c 10ab is in it.

How do i do this? Is there a way to do this WITHOUT using vba? any help is greatly appreciated as my data spans 25 columns and is over 2000 rows deep. 
Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with the result of your search? i.e. can you use conditional formatting to just visually point out the search term, or do you need to extract some other info from that row? How are your data formatted and what is your expected output?

Comment: Brad, my data looks like this:


ROW 1: blank cell; 10ab; 10b,10ac; blank cell; 10a1,10ab;
ROW 2: 9a2a; 11f; 5af, 6bc; blank cell; 2e, 1b

Comment: Brad, my data looks like this:
ROW 1: blank cell; 10ab; 10b,10ac; blank cell; 10a1,10ab;
ROW 2: 9a2a; 11f; 5af, 6bc; blank cell; 2e, 1b
two rows semicolon=nextcell Its a sample of my AD2:AX2341 data set. I have another data set that is in one column. It consists of all those values listed above (most). I want to highlight all cells in the AD:AX data range if they exist in my single column data set. However, having "10b,10ac" in one cell i am finding difficulty in doing so. NOTE: if multiple values exist in  AD:AX they are consistently separated with like so "xx, YY" (a comma then a space)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only that you have multiple data in single cells, you my find useful the Microsoft article on [Spliting text into different cells](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/split-text-into-different-cells-HA102809804.aspx). Then the complexity of your problem will be reduced.

Comment: This works beautifully for single column data. However, my data is in range AD2:AX2341. Not all cells in that range have a value but some have multiple values. See my comment to Brad above.

Comment: How does look look like your referential data - the data you are searching for? Are there many of them and are they variable? Or how often do they change?

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should help you:

=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,**"a"**,"|",1))**-2**,LEN(A1)),"",REPT(**"b"**,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))

The formula is going to extract the values of interest.  You can utilize an IF statement to compare the values that are extracted with the formula with the values in your list for conditional formatting.

in this case, IF(Output from above formula = "10ab","True","False")

The characters in **bold** are the parameters you will need to change for the conditional formatting.  the reason i highlighted -2 is because when it finds **a** it will move 2 characters to the left (- mean it moves to the left while + mean it moves to the right)

I'm not sure what the rest of your conditions look like but this should get you started.

Source is from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/444266-extract-string-between-two-characters.html).